# Saving an Association with CakeDC Users

Tags: php, cakephp-4.x, cakedc

I am using CakeDC Users and as part of the registration I would like the registrant to choose some checkbox values that correspond to another Model in the application. I am able to get the form to load the choices just fine, but I am unable to get it to save to the join table even though I have added all of the associations and accessibilities where it would seem relevant. The form is displaying in a similar way to other areas where I am saving the same type of association with a different model.

TypesTable.php

````
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        //$this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->setDisplayField('type');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->belongsToMany('Words');
        $this->belongsToMany('Users');
        $this->belongsTo('Languages', [
            'foreignKey' => 'language_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
    }```

UsersTable.php (in the plugin folders)
```class UsersTable extends Table
{
   ...
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setDisplayField('username');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->addBehavior('CakeDC/Users.Register');
        $this->addBehavior('CakeDC/Users.Password');
        $this->addBehavior('CakeDC/Users.Social');
        $this->addBehavior('CakeDC/Users.LinkSocial');
        $this->addBehavior('CakeDC/Users.AuthFinder');
        $this->hasMany('SocialAccounts', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'className' => 'CakeDC/Users.SocialAccounts',
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('Types', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id', 'targetForeignKey' => 'type_id',
        'joinTable' => 'types_users']);
    }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a "belongsToMany" association to work in this instance, both *Table.php files must have the relations listed as belongsToMany. Don't forget to make the field accessible in the Entities as well.

One also needs to place the associated array in the patchEntity function in the RegisterBehavior.php file.

UserTable.php (in CakeDC users)

```
public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        ...
        $this->belongsToMany('Types', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id', 'targetForeignKey' => 'type_id',
        'joinTable' => 'types_users']);
    }
```

TypesTable.php (in app)

```
class TypesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
       ....
        $this->belongsToMany('Users');
        $this->belongsTo('Languages', [
            'foreignKey' => 'language_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
    }
```

RegisterBehavior.php

```
$user = $this->_table->patchEntity(
            $user,
            $data,
            ['validate' => $validator ?: $this->getRegisterValidators($options), 'associated' => ['Types']]
        );
```